# Method's param - requiring both a class and interface at the same time

Tags: java

I have a class Context. It's required to be passed to and used in an another class'es constructor - called, say, Manager. But the context variable must be also an implementation of MyInterface, which obligates to implement a requiredMethod(). So I wanted to be something like:

```
class Manager {
    Manager(Context context) {
        context.doSomeStandardContextStuff();
        if (context instanceof MyInterface) {
            context.requiredMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

However, a compilator and IDE tell me that requiredMethod() cannot be solved.

So am I obliged in order to solve this issue to create an "artificial" another class, which extends from Context class, and implements MyInterface - just in order to use it as a single object in the constructor above? Or there's a better solution to do this?

Comment: try: ((MyInterface) context).requiredMethod()

Comment: In your `if` statement, you can guarantee that `context` is of `MyInterface`, so just cast it : `((MyInterface)context).requiredMethod()`

Comment: Could you override `doSomeStandardContextStuff()` on that object so that it additionally calls `requiredMethod()` from inside? Your example is pretty cryptic, so I'm not sure if it would fit.

Comment: @4castle I can't, because this is a framework class, not my own - except a case when I extended Context, which is actually the same as creating a "garbage" class, something I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Are you using an anonymous class then? I don't see how you could create an object that extends `Context` and `MyInterface` at the same time if you haven't created an implementation with that combination.

Comment: This indicates a problem in your design. Either all `Context`s should implement that interface, or you shouldn't be mixing concerns in that single parameter.

Comment: Well... now it's a purely theoretical talk, I solved it with the David's suggestion, but in brief, the Context is actually the Activity (which is a child to Conext) in Android. I need however to "bind" somehow two Views (being actually a part of Activity) to the Manager. I decided that it'd be stupid to pass these Views to the Manager seperately, since I need to pass to it Context anyway, which - being technically Activity - already is supposed to contain these two Views. Hence, I created an interface which API allows to get these View instances from Activity (= Context). :)

Comment: I'm still confused. Why did you need to create an interface when `Activity` already has the needed methods? Couldn't you do `instanceof Activity`?

Comment: Activity as a class doesn't have the particular Views - but only those, which I (as a programmer) would add to it at a run time. These Views are custom Views I've created - they're containers that need a data from Manager to be mangaged and stored into them. So in order to get those custom, specific (not any) Views, I created methods like getViewContainer(), which are a part of the MyInterface, as in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This checks if the variable is an instance of the type at runtime:

```
if (context instanceof MyInterface)
```

But it *doesn't* resolve the variable to that type at compile time.  To do that, you can cast it:

```
if (context instanceof MyInterface) {
    ((MyInterface)context).requiredMethod()
}
```

Comment: Wow, it does work. Didn't know that Java is able to cast a class to an interface, which is outside a particular classes hierarchy. Thx a lot, fortunetely there's no need to create a "garbage class" in Java.

Comment: @forsberg: Technically you can *try* to cast between any reference types, regardless of their polymorphic relation or lack thereof.  If the variable is of that type at runtime, it'll be fine.

Comment: This will compile, but if you read the OP's new comments, it won't fix the design issue. The `instanceof` statement will never be `true` since they don't have any classes that extend both.

Comment: @4castle: Interesting.  Yes, there would have to be a type which inherits from `Context` and itself implements `MyInterface`.  If `Context` itself (or any of its ancestors) doesn't implement the interface then the condition would never be satisfied.  But if that's the case then what the OP is trying to do wouldn't make any sense at all.  If no type satisfies this requirement then, well, no type satisfies this requirement.

Comment: Well. But couldn't an interface instance (context var) be just casted to the Object? Then, everything could be satisfied, right?

Comment: @forsberg: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  The `context` variable would have to be a `Context` type to be passed to this method, and would have to be a `MyInterface` type to satisfy the condition.  If `Context` doesn't implement `MyInterface`, and if no class inherits from `Context`, then nothing satisfies both of those conditions.

Comment: Why not just use a bounded type as suggested by the other answer?

Comment: @MickMnemonic: That's certainly another way of approaching the method itself (by avoiding the cast operation, at least explicitly in the code), but there still needs to exist a variable of a type which satisfies both polymorphic types.

Comment: @David I meant basically how casting, as in your answer, could actually work: since Java compiler doesn't have a problem with such a statement as you wrote (casting to interface), regardless the fact that MyInterface has nothing to do with the Context class itself, (but as we know everything is of an Object class in Java), it might be that Java (1st) casts context var up to the Object, and then casts it again down to MyInterface. Hence, it could be satisified.

Comment: @forsberg: The two types don't have to be related, the compiler doesn't try to resolve a cast operation.  The runtime does.  Casting basically tells the compiler that you're guaranteeing something it can not.  And while I don't know the internals of Java that deeply, I don't think it "goes through `Object`" in any way in a casting operation.  It simply attempts to interpret the object in the heap as the type specified.  If the runtime object satisfies that type, the cast succeeds.  If it doesn't, the cast fails.

Comment: @David, and that's exactly the situation OP has, right ("context variable must be also an implementation of MyInterface")? Without the bounded type, there is a chance for a programming error which the compiler cannot catch: passing in a parameter that doesn't implement `MyInterface`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic: The double-bound type essentially does the same thing that the `if` statement already does, it just does it somewhere else.  (And perhaps more efficiently or safely?  Someone with more knowledge of the internals of Java could speak to that.)  But both achieve the same thing.  As long as a variable which satisfies both types is provided, it works.  The main advantage I see to the double-bound type (which is something I didn't know about, so I'm glad you pointed it out) seems to be that it performs that conditional check at compile time instead of runtime.

Comment: @David ok, I see. You're talking about a "programming safety", e.g. that I assume that I will get MyInterface instance (being a Context instance) in the Magager constructor. But that's not a big problem, because I can always do sth like: else { throw new Exception(); }

Comment: Yes, exactly. And that's a _big_ advantage: you want to catch bugs compile-time, not run-time.

Comment: @MickMnemonic: Both approaches are perfectly safe.  The `if` condition guarantees that the type is polymorphic before it attempts the cast operation.  But as a general rule your statement is true.

Comment: @David, I'll try to explain my point once more: this version is not safe if you're assuming that `requiredMethod()` is always executed (which I think is implied by OP's description). The other version _guarantees_ that the method is executed.

Comment: @MickMnemonic: Good point.  I guess I assumed that the `if` statement in the original code implied that the method should *conditionally* be executed.  If the OP does indeed want that guarantee, the other approach would provide that.

Answer (score 4):

You can make the constructor generic, and have a double type bound:

```
<T extends Context & MyInterface> Manager(T context) {
    context.doSomeStandardContextStuff();
    context.requiredMethod();
}
```

This avoids having to cast at all.

---

However, you could also specify the implementation type. i.e.:

```
class Implementation extends Context implements MyInterace {...}
```

```
Manager(Implementation i) {...}
```

Or, in the case you have multiple implementations, create a common supertype:

```
abstract class Union extends Context implements MyInterface {}
```

```
class Implementation extends Union {...}
```

```
Manager(Union u) {...}
```

`Union` would be a dummy class, but would still be more efficient than the generic version.

Since the generic version gets erased to have `Context` as a parameter, and has to be cast (behind the scenes) to `MyInterface` every time you want to call a method from `MyInterface`.

Comment: I like the bounded type approach, because it gives you type-safety (you get a compile error when trying to pass an object that doesn't implement the interface) and cleans up the code when you don't need to do type-casting.